# Why JDBC is ill-advised with Android Development

Tags: android, jdbc

I have read countless posts regarding the use of JDBC with Android. Everybody suggests to take the path of using PHP scripts and using HTTP clients within the Android code.

It would be great to just get a clear indication as to why the JDBC is not advised.

Comment: So you want to give everyone your database password?

Comment: I'll refer back to my answer on this closed SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858099/using-jdbc-in-android

Answer (score 7):

JDBC access directly from a web client, be it browser or web phone, implies that the database port is exposed on the public internet.  That's not a safe place for any data to be.

I think a better approach is to put one or more servlets between clients and the database.  Let the servlet(s) handle security, validation, binding, deciding which services to invoke to fulfill the use case, marshaling the response, and routing to the next page depending on the outcome.

This design lets you put the intermediate layer on the internet and keep your data safe behind a firewall.

It's called Model-2 MVC.  It's been the standard idiom for Java web development for more than ten years.

You'll get a lot more use out of your code if you have a clean separation of the presentation of data from how it's produced.  UIs come and go, but services and data linger.  Think in terms of services first and you'll do better.