# Add mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 to Eclipse Android Developer Tools

Tags: java, android, mysql, osx-lion, eclipse-adt

I want the following line of code to work in Eclipse Java but apparently I need to import/add mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 to my eclipse android project so I can send a mySQL query via an android device.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

How can I add the mySQL library to a current project? I've seen other tutorials about doing this here at stack overflow but they've been kind of unspecific and just say "just ADD it to your current project" but that's where I'm stumped.

Most tutorials online just tell you how to start a new project from scratch, but I'm working with an android application.

Do I go to File>Import? and then select the .zip with the mySQL files? Or do I select the folder or something? I'm doing this on a Mac.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the MySQL database (device, PC, cloud) as Android already has SQLite built-in?

Comment: I own a godaddy server with mySQL, so I guess that makes it cloud

Comment: While not answering your question, I wouldn't just use JDBC over the internet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858099/using-jdbc-in-android

Comment: Just extract the zip file and import the jar file of mysql connector. This is only thing you need to do.

Comment: I've imported mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar to the project, still getting the ClassNotFoundException error on Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  do I need to have the "libs" folder selected and THEN import the jar file?

Comment: Is there any other way to send a simple mySQL query to my server???